How to use a glob pattern to find files in hidden directories using zsh
In zsh, echo **/asdf lists every file named asdf in the current directory and any subdirectories. But it doesn't search subdirectories whose names start with .. For example it wouldn't find .x/asdf. Is there a different pattern that can be used to also search hidden directories?

Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89749/cp-hidden-files-with-glob-patterns

ls **/asdf(D)

should do the job. D turns on dotglob for this pattern.
